# Solving the combination problem where a pattern is invalid (needs to be removed)

Tags: math, combinations, permutation

Problem is on N days, a student can be present or absent, but a student is not allowed to be absent for 3 or more consecutive days. Thus total number of combinations are - `2^N`, where every day there are only 2 options, A - Absent or P - Present

Let's take `N as 7`, which means total combinations are - `2^7 = 128`

Now Invalid patterns are ,  `AAA, AAAA, AAAAA, AAAAAA, AAAAAAA` so they need to be removed from total value and following is my understanding:

```
1. 3 Absent together:

    AAAP--- - 2^3 = 8
    ---PAAA - 2^3 = 8
    PAAAP-- - 2^2 = 4 * 3C1 (as there are such combinations) = 12
    Total - 28

2. 4 Absent together:
   AAAAP-- - 2^2 = 4
   --PAAAA - 2^2 = 4
   PAAAAP- - 2 *2 = 4
   Total - 12

3. 5 Absent together:
   AAAAAAP- - 2
   -PAAAAAA - 2
   PAAAAAP - 1
   Total - 5

4. 6 Absent together:
   AAAAAAP
   PAAAAAA
   Total - 2

5. 7 Absent together:
   AAAAAAA
   Total - 1
```

Total Invalid - 28 + 12 + 5 + 2 + 1 = 48

Total Valid Combinations - 128 - 48 = 80

Please let me know have I deduced it correctly, or there's something incorrect with my understanding

Comment: This is a math question, not a programming question.

Comment: @Sneftel what I have tagged it as, where is it tagged as a programming questions, atleast check, even when this is for an algorithm design for a programming problem. I have not asked for code anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's make recurrent equations. Valid combination of length `k` might end with 0, 1, or 2 "A"'s - denote numbers of such variants `v0, v1 and v2`.

We can make valid combination of length `k+1` with zero-ending "A"'s if we add "P" to any valid combination of length `k`

```
v0(k+1) = v0(k) + v1(k) + v2(k)
```

We can make valid combination of length `k+1` with one ending "A" if we add "A" to any zero-ending combination of length `k`

```
v1(k+1) = v0(k)
```

We can make valid combination of length `k+1` with two ending "A"'s if we add "A" to any one-ending combination of length `k`

```
v2(k+1) = v1(k)
```

Now look at Python code ([Ideone example](https://ideone.com/QECjhu))

```
v0 = 1
v1 = 0
v2 = 0
for i in range(10):
    v0, v1, v2 = v0 + v1 + v2, v0, v1
    print(i, v0)
```

Result is

```
0 1
1 2
2 4
3 7
4 13
5 24
6 44
7 81   
8 149
9 274
```

Note you have mistake `v(7) = 81`, not `80`

and this is [tribonacci sequence](http://oeis.org/A000073) with more simple recurrence expression:

```
 a(n) = a(n-1) + a(n-2) + a(n-3)
```

Comment: Thanks for a brilliant explanation this is very clear, is there a way for me to derive the same using permutations and combinations. I can see in my way I am trying to achieve the same from other end but I am adding an extra repetitive pattern, which is "AAAPAAA", due to which it leads to 80 instead of 81. Tribonacci explanation is brilliant

Comment: There are 2^4 variants when the first "AAA" is in 1st position, 2^3 variants when the first "AAA" is in 2nd position, 2^2 * 2  variants when the first "AAA" is in 3rd position (we multiply count of possible left and right parts), 2^1 * 4 variants when the first "AAA" is in 4th position, 7 variants when the first "AAA" is in 5th position. But this approach is not easy scalable because we must thoroughly apply inclusion-exclusion principle.